# Notepad++ Web Search text/convert text to url

Tags: google-chrome, notepad++, search

I'm wondering if it's possible to convert text to a Google or Bing search in Notepad++. For example, if I have:

> monarch butterflies
>
> corn chips
>
> cakes vs pies

in a .txt file, is there a way I can convert like

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=monarch+butterflies&oq=monarch+butterflies&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2097j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8


https://www.google.com/search?num=100&ei=gRrQW-GEDI7EsAXqkb7oDg&q=corn+chips&oq=corn+chips&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.58679.60016..60085...0.0..0.119.639.9j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j35i39j0i67j0i131j0i20i264j0i131i67j0i131i20i264.w0QKPtdQcVk
```

etc.?

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?q=monarch+butterflies` is already a valid url, what else do you need?

Comment: I want to change the plaintext (in the yellow box) to urls. I have over 300 plaintext words in my notepad file.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Is changing to `https://www.google.com/search?q=monarch+butterflies` enough, or do you need the whole complexity as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want "URLs" you can copy/past by hand, you may simply insert "https://www.google.com/search?q=" at the beginning of each line with a **Regular expression** Replace (Ctrl+H > check "Regular expression" Search mode) using :

1. a caret `^` (start of string) as *Find String*
2. `https://www.google.com/search?q=` as *Replace String*

You'll end up with strings like this :

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=monarch butterflies
```

If you copy and paste it in any browser, most of them will encode spaces and other special characters and it will work.

However, if you need to use resulting URLs with a script or something else, you might need to first encode special characters. For that, you can use the [MIME Tools](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Plugin_Central#M) Plugin and its **URL Encode** feature.

1. First select all the texte you want to use
2. Then encode it using Plugins > MIME Tools > URL Encode
3. The tool will also encode new lines, you need to replace them : replace the string `%0D%0A` with `\r\n\` checking **Extended Search mode** on the Replace dialog
4. Insert `https://www.google.com/search?q=` before each string as in the first exemple

You might also want to deal with empty lines first.

Please note that depending on your needs, there may be cleaner solutions than using Notepad++!